# IPhone UITableView suppress disclosure-button when Delete Button is displayed

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that has a disclosure button on every row.  When the table is put into edit mode and the the Deletion control is pressed ("-" sign), the Delete Button shows, however the disclosure button is not replaced, but instead just slides to the left of the delete button.

The apple `UITableView` guide explains the delegates for everything it seems except for the delegate that is called when the "-" sign is pressed, but before the delete button is displayed.

I would just like to suppress the disclosure indicator while the delete button is shown.

I'm guessing that I am missing something...  I have set the `setHidesAccessoryWhenEditing:NO`
on the cells of the table so that the indicator is displayed to indicate to the user that if they select the row, they can edit it...

The behavior I am trying to copy is done in the contacts app when a contact is edited.  Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks, Greg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use `cell.hidesAccessoryWhenEditing = YES`, and that editing is a modal action in which navigation is typically disabled.

The Contacts application actually uses custom table cells, and I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't so much use an accessory as have an image located on the cell's right edge, judging by its behaviour.

If you want to know when the delete button appears, I'd suggest that you try installing a Key-Value observer on the cell's `showingDeleteConfirmation` property, like so:

```
[cell addObserver: self forKeyPath: @"showingDeleteConfirmation"
          options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: NULL];
```

Then you implement the observer callback method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString *) keyPath ofObject: (id) object
                        change: (NSDictionary *) change context: (void *) context
{
    if ( [keyPath isEqualToString: @"showingDeleteConfirmation"] )
    {
        UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *) object;
        BOOL isShowing = [[change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
        if ( isShowing == NO )
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        else
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

I should note that I'm not sure whether the UITableViewCell class is KVO-compliant for this property, but it's got to be worth a try…

Comment: Jim,

Works like a charm!  I really appreciate you taking the time to respond...

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: In case anyone happens across your solution, just to be complete, add:

UITableViewCell * cell = object;

also:

Change  if ( isShowing )   -> if (! isShowing)...

Comment: Thanks,I've updated the answer to include those. Personally I like to use '== NO' rather than using ! in front, unless there's specific compiler support for boolean types (as in C++). The BOOL type from ObjC is just a typedef (I've been bitten before by word-size things & comparisons against char-sized BOOLs).

Comment: Personally I always try to state the positive case first in simple ifs like this, and then you don't even need to negate. You can also inline the if in the set. accessoryType = isShowing ? ... : ...

Answer (score 2):

Or when you are creating your cell you can define the accessory type: cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

Answer (score 1):

The disclosure indicator is managed by `tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:` so maybe you could change the accessory type while in editing mode.

I believe there's a `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`, maybe there you can note that you're going to edit mode and then change what the `tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:` returns for each row - no accessory when in edit mode.

I would give it a try.

Here is a calling sequence (not sure if that helps) description/tutorial/examples from Apple reference about how to go about [Inserting and Deleting Rows in Editing Mode](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

My comment to Jim's solution didn't come across very well...  Here is the version that solved the problem for me...  Thanks again Jim!

```
   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString *) keyPath ofObject: (id) object
                        change: (NSDictionary *) change context: (void *) context
  {
    UITableViewCell * cell = object;
    if ( [keyPath isEqualToString: @"showingDeleteConfirmation"] )
    {
        BOOL isShowing = [[change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
        if ( !isShowing )
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        else
        {

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
}
```